# How to implement frame skipping in MediaCodec android

Tags: android, video-encoding, android-mediacodec

I'm making an app which is using MediaCodec APIs.
The app runs on two phones. The first phone reads the video from the sdcard and then uses the MediaCodec encoder to encode the frames in avc format and then streams the frames to another device. The second device has a MediaCodec decoder running. The decoder decodes the frames and render them on a Surface. 
The code is running fine but after sometime when the size of the frames gets more, the first device is sometime not able to stream the video and the encoder stops reporting the following log :

```
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  212): Poll timedout, pipeline stalled due to client/firmware ETB: 496, EBD: 491, FTB: 492, FBD: 492
```

So I want to implement frame skipping on the encoder side.
What's the best way to skip the frames and not stream them to the other device. ?

PS. On a separate note if anyone can suggest me of any other way of streaming a video to other device it'll be really nice.

Comment: do you need realtime streaming or several seconds delay is ok?

Comment: I'm streaming in real time

Answer (score 0):

Please try Intel INDE Media Pack with tutorials on https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials. It has Camera, File and Game streaming components, which make streaming with help of Wowza and a set of samples demonstrating how to use it as a server and as a client

[image]

[image]